# What are the scoping rules for exception handling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, scope

I stumbled on an interesting scenario following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69464430/6045800). Consider the following simple example:

```
try:
    1/0
    error = "error"
except Exception as error:
    print(error)

print(error)
```

The output is:

```
division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(error)
NameError: name 'error' is not defined
```

What happens is of course the first assignment to `error` is skipped because of the exception, and the `except` is executed. It prints the exception and - to my understanding - assigns, in a way, the exception object to `error`. But then, surprisingly, the following `print` complains that `error` is not defined.

I tried to understand the scoping rule for exceptions but all I could find in the [Exceptions docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) was this:

> The variable is bound to an exception instance

Which doesn't really explain what is the scope or life-span of this exception instance.

The most similar construct I can think of is a `with` statement, which ***doesn't behave the same way***:

```
with open("test.txt") as file:
    pass

file.read()
```

This code will output a maybe expected output of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    file.read()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

But still it is not a `NameError` which means that `file` is well-defined.

So can anyone explain what are the scoping rules for exception handling and what is happening here?

Answer (score 3):

This is documented under, [*The try statement*](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

> When an exception has been assigned using `as target`, it is cleared
> at the end of the except clause. This is as if
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     foo
> ```
>
> was translated to
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     try:
>         foo
>     finally:
>         del N
> ```
>
> This means the exception must be assigned to a different name to be
> able to refer to it after the except clause